# Setting GtkEntry font from Pango.FontDescription

Tags: css, fonts, gtk, gtk3, styling

I have a GtkEntry that's I'd like to allow users to style with their choice of font (or system default). I end up with a Pango description string like "Monospace 10" to describe the font.

I'm currently using `override_font`, which is deprecated in favour of CSS styling.

I'd like to at least attempt to do it "right", but it seems like a pretty convoluted and fragile workflow now to get the CSS from the Pango string. Here's an [example from Github](https://github.com/otsaloma/gaupol/blob/master/gaupol/style.py):

```
def _get_editor_font_css():
    """Return CSS for custom editor font."""
    font_desc = Pango.FontDescription("monospace")
    if (gaupol.conf.editor.custom_font and
        gaupol.conf.editor.use_custom_font):
        font_desc = Pango.FontDescription(gaupol.conf.editor.custom_font)
    # They broke theming again with GTK+ 3.22.
    unit = "pt" if Gtk.check_version(3, 22, 0) is None else "px"
    css = """
    .gaupol-custom-font {{
      font-family: {family},monospace;
      font-size: {size}{unit};
      font-weight: {weight};
    }}""".format(
        family=font_desc.get_family().split(",")[0],
        size=int(round(font_desc.get_size() / Pango.SCALE)),
        unit=unit,
        weight=int(font_desc.get_weight()))
    css = css.replace("font-size: 0{unit};".format(unit=unit), "")
    css = css.replace("font-weight: 0;", "")
    css = "\n".join(filter(lambda x: x.strip(), css.splitlines()))
    return css
```

After the CSS is in a string, then I can create a `CSSProvider` and pass that to the style context's `add_provider()` (does this end up accumulating CSS providers, by the way?).

This all seems like a lot of work to get the font back into the system, where it presumably goes right back into Pango!

Is this really the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [PangoContext](https://developer.gnome.org/pangomm/stable/classPango_1_1Context.html).

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto GtkApp = Gtk::Application::create();

    Gtk::Window window;

    Gtk::Label label;
    label.set_label("asdasdfdfg dfgsdfg ");
    auto context = label.get_pango_context();
    auto fontDescription = context->get_font_description();
    fontDescription.set_family("Monospace");
    fontDescription.set_absolute_size(10*Pango::SCALE);
    context->set_font_description(fontDescription);

    Gtk::Label label2;
    label2.set_label("xcv");

    Gtk::VBox box;
    box.pack_start(label);
    box.pack_start(label2);
    window.add(box);
    window.show_all();
    GtkApp->run(window);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image: Resulting window]